# Вопрос по поводу переменной errno (expected an expression)

Tags: c, linux

Возникает ошибка на данном участке кода:

```
if (acc > cutoff || (acc == cutoff && c > cutlim)) {
            any = -1;
            acc = ULONG_MAX;
            errno = ERANGE;
} 

Ошибка: line 53: error: expected an expression

errno = ERANGE;
```

Исходный текст кода функции взят здесь: [strtoul.c](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/tiff/port/strtoul.c)

Значение переменной объявлено в errno.h
Сама переменная объявлена в локальном файле errno_local.h, который подключен к .c файлу:

```
#include "errno.h"
#ifndef errno
#define errno
#endif
```

Как я читал, переменная errno объявляется в errno.h и подключается к файлам как

```
extern int errno;
```

Но там она не была объявлена. Поэтому я создал локальный файл. 
Насколько я знаю, при таком объявлении переменная автоматически становится типом integer. Так ведь?

Comment: вообще то errno давно уже не просто переменная, а функция или набор define (из-за того, что бы нормально работать с многопоточностью).

Честно, я не понимаю, зачем Вы добавили объявление переменной, которая существует только в очень древних компиляторах.

Добавьте include errno и используйте переменную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда-то раньше, в самом деле, `errno` всегда можно было объявлять как

```
extern int errno;
```

Поскольку теперь программы потенциально могут быть многопоточными, а `errno` для каждого потока (нити исполнения или thread) д.б. *своя*, то ситуация изменилась.

Поэтому всегда просто пишите в своих программах

```
#include <errno.h>
```

что обеспечит правильное объявление этой переменной (которая логически действительно все еще соответствует extern int).

Например, в Linux в файле /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h (который подключается из /usr/include/errno.h) errno определяется вот так:

```
# ifndef __ASSEMBLER__
/* Function to get address of global `errno' variable.  */
extern int *__errno_location (void) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));

#  if !defined _LIBC || defined _LIBC_REENTRANT
/* When using threads, errno is a per-thread value.  */
#   define errno (*__errno_location ())
#  endif
# endif /* !__ASSEMBLER__ */
#endif /* _ERRNO_H */
```

Т.е. на самом деле память, выделенная под переменную спрятана, а ее текущий (актуальный) адрес выдает функция `__errno_location()`.

Кстати, можете запомнить этот полезный (в некоторых ситуациях) прием.

Comment: уточнение: *в Linux в файле /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h (который подключается из /usr/include/errno.h)* — оба эти файла входит в состав не программы *linux*, а библиотеки *glibc*.